# Google Daydream Unity3D demo red point NOT on right place when rotate it up or below

Tags: unity-game-engine, daydream

I'm want use the red point, which in daydream controller demo, to my project but I find it will be offset to wrong place when rotate it up or below that comparing with a raying.
Raying and the red point will be coincide at beginning. They are in same transform coordinate.

How can I fix red point to the same place of raying?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not the Unity or daydream's problem.The reason is the raying cast I'm using `transform.forward` as direction but will be some accumulated error make the raying 20 meter distance position differ the actual value.

So, replace `transform.forward` by `redPoint.position - cameraPosition` as the raying direction can fix this.